# Why is the Spring boot caching configuration not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching, spring-cache

I have a simple Spring boot application that interacts with a custom jar to GET data from a third party application.

My Spring boot application class looks like this:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
public class TestApplication {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

I have a controller like this (which calls a service method):

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/getTestData.spr"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public JsonView getTestData(@RequestParam(value = "childProjectIdKeyName", required = false) String childProjectIdKeyName) {
   
   //Get All Test Case Data
   testRunsFromTracker = testRunProgressService.getAllTestRunListByProjects(childProjectIdKeyName);

   //Some other logic that returns a JSON View to the front-end
   return new JsonView(someManipulatedCollectionDataHere)
}
```

And the service class that is being called looks like this:

```
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class TestService {
@Cacheable (cacheNames = "testRun", key = "#childProjectIdKeyName")
   public List<TrackerItemDto> getAllTestRunListByProjects(String childProjectIdKeyName) {
      System.out.println(String.format("-----getAllTestRunListByProjects(%s)-----", childProjectIdKeyName));
      //-----some complex code that take a long time to execute everytime it is called-----//
}
```

I have my `pom.xml` include the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Everytime I call the controller that calls in the mentioned `TestService`, I get the console printed in stating that I am still missing something to make caching work.
The service method is called everytime which is NOT expected after the caching implementation.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: I think you should use ehcache configuration to mention all the cache name in ehcache.xml and make the cache work.

Comment: This should work with default ConcurrentMapCacheManager. Can you share a demo app to troubleshoot? Also, implement a CacheEventListener to see if caching events are getting triggered.

Comment: My end goal was a more complex and custom caching system using `caffeine cache`. Though I am stuck struggling with default cache management of spring boot.
I will share a sample code as well.

Comment: Please add the calling code and make sure you actually have a cache configured.

Comment: M. Deinum 
I have added the `calling` code in the question.
I am not sure about the secod part of your suggestion.  Ho do I `make sure that I have cache configured`. All the configuration have been mentioned in the question. Is there anything more required?

Comment: @Einstein_AB - We use `cache2k` and it works really great. You should be able to use `caffeine`. Also, enable the logs for cache by setting `org.springframework.cache` to `TRACE` or `DEBUG`.

Comment: What you've posted here looks fine... I'm thinking if perhaps you haven't set `spring.cache.type=none` in your configuration file? If not, then do enable Spring cache logs (as mentioned in one of the comments) and see if you can find any useful info there

Comment: Yes, probably you missed something, however its not in you example. How did you get the reference to the `TestService`? You need to retrieve it via Sping DI, e.g. with `@Injet`. You will get a proxy from Spring that does the caching. @Tushar, thanks for recommending [cache2k](https://cache2k.org/)!

Comment: @Einstein_AB - If you can create a working git repo we can take a look.